# Make Connection to AS400 in Excel to update 2 worksheets with data from 2 Tables?

Tags: excel, refresh, excel-2007, ibm-midrange, vba

I have an Excel workbook with several worksheets. I need to connect to AS400 and make it to where when users click refresh, 2 worksheets ([Feedname] & [Feedprod]) are updated with data from 2 tables on the 400.

Anyone know how to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

ODBC is the typical way this is done.  There is an ODBC driver that comes with [IBM i Access].[1](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_functions.html)